# Is ucLibc malloc thread safe?

Tags: multithreading, thread-safety, malloc, uclibc

Is ucLibc malloc thread safe?

Answer (score 2):

Apparently yes, if `__UCLIBC_HAS_THREADS__` is defined *malloc.h* includes and declares mutexes http://git.uclibc.org/uClibc/tree/libc/stdlib/malloc/malloc.h#n133